# How many different versions of Fry are frozen in the Cryogenics Lab in Futurama?

Tags: time-travel, futurama

In a number of episodes of Futurama, Fry and other characters travel back in time numerous times, to freeze and unfreeze themselves, and do various other actions in the cryogenics lab.

How many different versions of Fry and various other characters are in and around the cryogenics chambers at what times?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'll just list who are frozen in the lab while various Frys are frozen there.

- First there is the first Fry from the first episode, [Space Pilot 3000](http://theinfosphere.org/Space_Pilot_3000).
- Fry 2 would have been from [The Why of Fry](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Why_of_Fry) however they changed it at the last minute to avoid having to do a lengthy montage.
- Fry 2 actually was from [Bender's Big Score](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Big_Score) in which the above segment was finally realized. This is when Fry climbs in behind himself, and pulls up his own pants.
- Fry 3 is a spoiler for the above movie.
- Fry 4 is from *The Cryonic Woman*, where Michelle and Fry both enter Pauly Shore's tube for a few days, but this is technically Fry 1 again... But they are all technically Fry 1, so I'm adding it.

In addition to Fry:

- Bender, again from the above movie.
- [Michelle](http://theinfosphere.org/Michelle), Fry's ex-girlfriend.
- [Pauly Shore](http://theinfosphere.org/Pauly_Shore).
- Maybe [That Guy, Steve Castle](http://theinfosphere.org/That_Guy), from [Future Stock](http://theinfosphere.org/Future_Stock).
- Some old man, that Fry and Bender torture in [The Cryonic Woman](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Cryonic_Woman).
- And seen through the glass, [Weird Al Yankovic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic).
- Also Leela, for 5 minutes, technically while a Fry is also in the same pod.

Comment: Whenever I think I know a lot about a show... someone always proves that I'm not really that much of an addict... good call.

Comment: @WernerCD: Don't feel bad, man. I'm the biggest fan of this show that has ever lived. I literally go to bed each night listening to it. I've seen the commentary of the new season more times than you've likely seen the pilot. I'm an anomaly.

Comment: What about when fry WORKED in the cryogenics lab? He took naps in the cryo chamber...

Answer (score 0):

Fry from the pilot. Then 2 Frys during the strange events of the first movie. And a fourth Fry when him and his girlfriend "went 1,000 years in the future". So in total 4 in the canon so far there very well could be more in the future of the series.