# Does Fry ever actually pay for his cryogenic freezing?

Tags: futurama

Fry has frozen himself [multiple times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2867/20533), but he never seems to incur any sort of bill for this cryogenic freezing process.  The future definitely still has money, so why doesn't Fry ever have to pay for this process?

Comment: ♪"Repeat to yourself it's just a show, I should really just relax..."♫

Comment: @MeatTrademark Even though I approve the mantra, this is the last place I would go if I didn't want to ask questions that were never meant to be answered.

Comment: I'm just having fun at a place I can make that comment. I see your Rep; I know you belong. No worries.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I know.  I see your rep, and am poking fun back at your comment.  ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this is never addressed on screen.

**Alternatives**

- ***Off-screen, either Al Gore or the Nibblonians took care of the costs.***

Both groups are fully aware that the fate of the entire universe depends on Fry remaining frozen at the cryo-centre. Neither group seem to lack the funds to ensure that this takes place.

- ***Off-screen, Fry took care of the costs.***

Fry travels into his own past on at least three occasions. There's no reason to assume that he couldn't pay for the tube in advance. And yes, I'm aware that this is a [bootstrap paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_paradox). Go to hell, logic!

- ***The cryo-centre didn't notice or didn't care.***

Civilisation has collapsed on at least three occasions since Fry was frozen. It's certainly possible that the cryo-centre's HQ (and its billing centre) were in a building that didn't survive.

[image]

Comment: +1. Another alternative: Fry paid for it himself using the immense wealth he had in "A Fish full of dollars" - possibly when the collection department finally tracked him down.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - Ah, but they didn't know who he was.

Comment: Cryo tube occupant #157783 mysteriously disappears. A couple of months later, a previously frozen 20th century halfwit makes the news when he discovers he is a billionaire and spends a ridiculous sum of money on anchovies. Collections might have put two and two together. :-)

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - In which case, the police and his parents would have seen some activity on his account. Don't forget that his brother never stopped looking.

Comment: ??? I'm talking about events in the year 3000. Fry's parents and brother had been dead for centuries.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - That happened years after he was defrosted. Most debts lapse when you find out that the debtor has no money.

Comment: Wouldn't a lawyer argue that hs debt wasn't actually 'due' until he was defrosted?  There are many services that you pay for after you have used the service.

Comment: @Zoredache - If you use a service by accident, it's pretty rare to get billed.

Comment: @Richard: Tell that to the hooker I thought was just really into my *Star Wars* collection that one time.

Comment: It can happen to the best of us; http://edition.cnn.com/SHOWBIZ/9705/02/murphy/

Comment: @Valorum "Most debts lapse when you find out that the debtor has no money." Hah, not in the Netherlands, they don't. Here debtors are fined again and again for having no money. Recent documented cases: A 40 euro debt that expanded to 1000 euro's, a woman who was fined 120 euro's for parking an unregistered motor cycle on the sidewalk: zeven or eight years later she's more than six thousand in debt -- to the government, mind. So, I'd say with interest and fines, Fry probably owes more than the universe is worth.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij - Sure, but she's still alive and I'm willing to bet she's got money.

Answer (score 17):

Typically you would pay upfront for cryogenic freezing. The fact that he falls into them on accident multiple times, leads me to believe that since he was already frozen the people running the place must have assumed he had already paid. (Billing never talks to the scientists; a typical lack of communication between departments)

Comment: At least one or two of those incidents weren't accidental though.  I can think of one specifically, but it is a spoiler for the movie.

Comment: another possibility is since he is still alive when they put him in, they may actually owe him money since hes testing unsure tech (as in he could die doing it), but since hes dumb its free for him.

Comment: 'currently' illegal yes, but remember this series began (and Fry got frozen) at the dawn of the year 2000.

Comment: But will it always be?

Comment: @Zibbobz the distant future year 2000 :)

Comment: @Himarm found the solution. No extra explanation needed. Prank order a pizza, they left the door unsecured, someone potentionally "died" under their watch, nobody's forming a search team, leave him quietly in place and avoid monstrous legal fees. Waking him costs money at the time, failing to waking him and letting him would cost more money. Leave him frozen? Minor cost increase for the next CEO. He stays where he is.